# SoundManager2 - using RTMP not displaying duration

Tags: javascript, rtmp, soundmanager2

I'm using SoundManager2 to stream mp3 audio via RTMP. The problem is that the duration is not being generated and is always 0

```
var sound = soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'soundid',
            serverURL: 'rtmp://server/',
            url: 'file.mp3',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoPlay: false,
            onload: function() {
                console.log("DURATION: ", this.duration);
            },
            whileplaying: function() {
                console.log(this.duration);
            },
            volume: 100
        }).play();
```

Is getting the duration possible using RTMP? I've tried `durationEstimate` as well and this also displays 0.

Answer (score 0):

By default Soundmanager2, with RTMP, doesn't calculate the duration, in contrast, you should provide it (in microseconds) as a parameter, otherwise, you will not be able to seek (SetPosition(value)):

```
var sound = soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'soundid',
            serverURL: 'rtmp://server/',
            url: 'file.mp3',
            duration: 300000,//example for a 5 minutes song
            autoLoad: true,
            autoPlay: false,
            onload: function() {
                console.log("DURATION: ", this.duration);
            },
            whileplaying: function() {
                console.log(this.duration);
            },
            volume: 100
        }).play();
```

If you don't have the duration of your mp3 music, try to fetch it with the mp3's ID3 meta data (you can get them with javascript).